# Google TV emulator not able to play HLS

Tags: streaming, android-videoview, http-live-streaming, google-tv

I have a google TV emulator for android 3.1 (API 12)
i am trying to play an hls file but I am getting the message "cannot play this video"

I am using the below code:

```
mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://vodmytvoriginrt-i.akamaihd.net/i/rotana/1RRCP0183_,500,1000,1800,.mp4.csmil/master.m3u8"));
mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(this);
mVideoView.setOnErrorListener(this);
MediaController mc = new MediaController(this, true);
mc.setMediaPlayer(mVideoView);
mc.setAnchorView(mVideoView);
mVideoView.setMediaController(mc);
mVideoView.requestFocus();
```

mVideoView.start();

What could i be possibly missing? does anyone has a solution or suggestion for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

emulator for Google TV does not support HLS. I will file a feature request for this. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your response, so how should i be able to test if the streaming in my application is working? should i use a physical device? or can i just test the streaming on any other android emulator

Comment: my google TV emulator is working fine for the rest of the features but Can I use a sony media player to test my application? if yes any useful link on how to do that?