# Does GoogleTV emulator support Http Live Streaming?

Tags: google-tv

I am trying to play an HLS video on GoogleTV Emulator.But, unable to do so.
Can anyone suggest me, what could be the issue.
I saw a similar post on this forum(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11974141/google-tv-emulator-not-able-to-play-hls), which was answered on August,2012 as "Emulator doesn't support HLS".I wanted to know if this feature has been enabled on GoogleTV emulator or not?
If yes, Is there any DRM requirement to play an HLS video on GoogleTV emulator.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't work - Emulator doesn't play media.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation!!! Does Google has any future plan to enable HLS on GoogleTV Emulator? If yes, could you please provide the approx. period of time(when it would be enabled), it will take.

Comment: No Plans - Why do you want an emulator for a low cost device?  It's much better to use the real thing.